# Exporting a Cassandra Keyspace with Data to a file

Tags: cassandra, nosql

Am trying to export a Cassandra Keyspace plus Data to a file. Is there a cqlsh command that allows the export of all tables + Data at once.?

I used this code to export the keyspace. Now I would like to export all the Data from all the tables into the file.

```
$ cqlsh -e "DESCRIBE KEYSPACE somekeyspace" > /path/to/somekeyspace.cql
```

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the [DataStax documentation](https://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cql/3.3/cql/cql_reference/cqlshCopy.html), you should be able to do that using the `COPY` command as follows (for a single table):

```
COPY someKeySpace.someTable (someCol1, someCol2) 
TO '/path/to/someTable_Col1Col2.csv' WITH HEADER = TRUE;
```

For all tables, probably you will need to write this code multiple times OR iterate through the tables. You might find [this article](https://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/simple-data-importing-and-exporting-with-cassandra) also useful.

ps. I also found this GitHub repo that seems interesting, but I haven't used it yet myself, so I am suggesting it here for you to maybe give it a try :)

https://github.com/masumsoft/cassandra-exporter

Comment: Thank you very much. I copied the data from the tables one by one

Answer (score 0):

Based on Taking a snapshot article in the Datastax you can get an snapshot of all tables included in on keyspace with the below commands,

```
nodetool cleanup mykeyspace
nodetool -h localhost -p 7199 snapshot mykeyspace
```

you can find detailed description in here:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsBackupTakesSnapshot.html